# “Installer wants access to control SystemUIServer” when installing Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

During installation of Anaconda, a message popped up:

"“Installer” wants access to control “SystemUIServer”. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “SystemUIServer”, and to perform actions within that app."

Sounds a little scary. If I click "Don't allow", it will lead to "the installation failed". Is it necessary to allow the access to install Anaconda?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Mac Monterey

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it in the following way:

- I installed anaconda with the brew command
  `brew install anaconda pycharm-with-anaconda-plugin`
- I added in the path of the .zshrc (in my case) /.bashrc

```
ANACONDABIN=/usr/local/anaconda3
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANACONDABIN/bin
```